# How to change first web page(master page?) in AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Maybe you can't understand my question in the title because I'm not sure that I express like this way.

Let me explain current situation and what I want to do.

I'm using AWS Amplify - CodeCommit and it is working well.

However I want to change first page connected to do the master(https://master.xxxxx.amplifyapp.com/)

For example, when I connect to https://master.xxxxx.amplifyapp.com/, a.html is showing now but I want to show b.html.

Could you let me know how to do this?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Which Framework/Library are you using to write your code?
That'll probably help me figure out how to help you out...

Comment: I'm not using framework. I did like serverless(https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/module-1/). I use boto3 because I created Lambda function with Python.